# ESXi VM networking to local LAN

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation, esxi

I have just installed ESXi 6.7.0 (free version) and setup my first two VM's with the default settings. But **I cannot seem to get these VM's to connect and ping devices on my local network**. I can, though, reach the internet with the default settings?? So traffic seems to pass fine from my vmware host NIC to my router and out my demarc to the internet, but I cannot get communication between VM's and my home laptops.

After searching and digging through MANY forums, KB's, videos and doc's I cannot seem to get an answer on how to set this up on the web-portal of the esxi host. Many posts mention VLAN setups, bridging and VM workstation (which I dont have or need). I cannot find any bridging settings on the vswitch, vmnic, port groups or network settings. I dont VLAN tag my local network and my testing VLAN's have lead me no-where.

Am I crazy? Is this a limitation of VMware ESXi? Does the free version not allowing local networking and no-one wants to talk about it??

I really do feel like I'm taking crazy pills...

**UPDATE:**
Hey, thanks for the response essjae! After some review everything seems correct, the guest OS has the right IP, gateway, DNS info, infact the DHCP assigned IP is within my routers range. The ESXi guest os's seem to be able to reach the router and pull DHCP.

After some further digging things have gotten even weirder:
-The VM's can ping several of my other devices (my laptop, phone, raspberry pi) in the LAN but it cannot reach my workstation
-The VM's cannot ping each other WITHIN the same host machine
-Troubleshooting brought me to a post about VM's not being able to ping each other, it was recommended to use adapter "E1000" instead of "VMXNET 3", my VM's are already on that adapters type, switching to "VMXNET 3" did not help.

TLDR I was able to get VM's to reach LAN devices BUT VM's cannot ping some devices, or each other.

The saga continues (with crazy pills)...

Comment: There are no local networking restrictions for ESXi, you've got a misconfiguration of your network settings. Can you share your network information (TCP/IP) for the host and one of the guests?  Verify your DNS, gateway, subnet, etc, is all correct.

Comment: Are you sure your other devices are configured to respond to ping? Try connecting some other way like a web server